# Suddenly cannot connect to website over Wi-Fi but can connect to it from my smartphone

Tags: router, connection, website

I am hosting my site—`strongjoshua.com`—with [easyDNS](http://easydns.com)'s web hosting service. Yesterday, I was trying to connect to the CPanel of my site, but I couldn’t remember the password. I tried a few variations but I eventually gave up, so I requested a password reset. That was taking a while to process so I decided to give one last password a try, upon which I received a network error.

I assumed that was because the password reset, but I still thought it was strange. Then I check my email and received the reset email. But after that, I was no longer able to access my site. The CPanel is hosted on the website itself, so I am unable to access that either.

I am unable to access the site only from my home Wi-Fi, but using data with a phone works like normal. I have tried changing my router’s DNS servers to [Google’s](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)—including the IPv6 ones—but to no avail.

My traceroute is:

```
Tracing route to strongjoshua.com [64.68.202.30]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.0.0.1
  2   102 ms   112 ms    31 ms  98.221.240.1
  3    14 ms    11 ms     9 ms  te-1-2-ur02.raritan.nj.panjde.comcast.net [68.85
.78.13]
  4    28 ms    25 ms    11 ms  xe-4-0-1-0-ar03.audubon.nj.panjde.comcast.net [6
8.85.63.65]
  5    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  he-2-14-0-0-cr01.newyork.ny.ibone.comcast.net [6
8.86.166.113]
  6     *       14 ms    13 ms  ae12.edge1.NewYork2.level3.net [4.68.127.1]
  7    26 ms    27 ms    32 ms  ae-2-23.edge1.Toronto2.Level3.net [4.69.200.238]

  8    36 ms    35 ms    36 ms  4.31.208.150
  9    36 ms    42 ms    36 ms  te-1-1.core01.tor1.prioritycolo.com [204.11.48.1
30]
 10    48 ms    42 ms    38 ms  c.gi-3-5.core03.tor2.prioritycolo.com [67.223.96
.82]
 11    36 ms    37 ms    37 ms  173.237.223.2 [173.237.223.2]
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.

 [times out up until 30 tries and ends with “trace complete.”]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Shorter Answer

I don’t think the password reset request has anything to do with this, but it seems like the hosting service itself—or your configuration on it—is choking. I would recommend logging into the control panel from a computer that can get a connection to your site and/or contacting your hosting provider to ask them to investigate.

#### Longer Answer

Nothing I am seeing points to this being a client-solvable source ISP issue and here is why.

I am in Brooklyn, NY, USA and I can view your site fine if I access it via the hostname `strongjoshua.com`:

[image]

But, if I attempt to access it via the IP address of `64.68.202.30`, I get a dead-end/error page setup by the hosting provider:

[image]

That tells me that the hosting provider is using some kind of name-based virtual host [such as the one that Apache uses](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html):

> Name-based virtual hosting is usually simpler, since you need only
>   configure your DNS server to map each hostname to the correct IP
>   address and then configure the Apache HTTP Server to recognize the
>   different hostnames. Name-based virtual hosting also eases the demand
>   for scarce IP addresses. Therefore you should use name-based virtual
>   hosting unless you are using equipment that explicitly demands
>   IP-based hosting.

Which basically means, potentially dozens of hosts can have the same IP address on the same web server, but what will differentiate them on a web server level is the actual hostname. So accessing via the raw IP address will result in an error, but accessing it via the hostname of `strongjoshua.com` will send you to the correct site.

All that said, it still doesn’t explain the issues you are seeing. So using [`mtr`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mtr)—which is a nicer version of [`traceroute`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) that combines route tracing with continually updated [`ping`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) data—you can see the following:

```
 Host                                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. ???
 2. 10.42.37.197                      0.0%    11  189.0 200.8 176.9 255.6  27.1
 3. 66.233.174.161                    0.0%    11  188.6 198.9 167.3 378.9  60.2
 4. 66.233.174.253                    0.0%    11  199.0 212.9 178.7 293.2  35.7
 5. sl-crs2-nyc-.sprintlink.net       0.0%    11  189.8 196.2 154.8 259.5  25.2
 6. 144.232.10.198                    0.0%    11  350.5 202.7 174.4 350.5  52.3
 7. xe-10-3-0.tor10.ip4.gtt.net      10.0%    11  315.8 269.1 238.6 372.9  46.1
 8. db-transit-gw.ip4.gtt.net         0.0%    10  205.9 221.2 193.5 259.3  18.0
 9. te-1-1.core01.tor1.prioritycolo.  0.0%    10  231.2 244.1 219.9 302.5  29.2
10. c.gi-3-5.core03.tor2.prioritycol  0.0%    10  301.2 237.3 209.5 301.2  25.3
11. 173.237.223.2                     0.0%    10  216.7 227.7 214.2 237.0   9.0
12. cpanel5.easyweb.com               0.0%    10  341.9 252.6 220.5 341.9  40.1
```

Now it superficially looks exactly like your `traceroute`—with differences between initial hops due to my physical location versus yours—but also note the last two hops:

```
11. 173.237.223.2                     0.0%    10  216.7 227.7 214.2 237.0   9.0
12. cpanel5.easyweb.com               0.0%    10  341.9 252.6 220.5 341.9  40.1
```

And here are the relevant lines from your `traceroute` for comparison:

```
11    36 ms    37 ms    37 ms  173.237.223.2 [173.237.223.2]
12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Your `traceroute` timeouts happen right after reaching `173.237.223.2` and via `mtr` I can see the reverse DNS (PTR) entry for the last hop which is `cpanel5.easyweb.com`.

What does this all mean? Well it seems like if you compare what you are seeing—or not seeing—versus what I am seeing, it’s clear we are both getting to the hosting provider’s IP address of `173.237.223.2`; might be a router or a switch in their network. But you dead-end on your access and I end up seeing the site without issue.

So if you ask me, something is happening on the hosting provider’s side that is somehow blocking your access. Perhaps it’s a firewall setting or something similar on an application level, but I don’t see this as being a networking issue you can solve from your side.

I would recommend contacting your hosting provider or logging into your control panel from a system you can use to connect to your hosting provider and see if you can debug it from there. Or at least open up a support ticket with your hosting provider asking them to check into your site’s config.

Comment: Yeah, I emailed them about it already. Thanks for going in-depth, it made it much easier to understand. I'll mark this as the answer if you end up being correct and the problem is solved :)

Comment: I just checked, but I am unable to even reach that dead-end page you got. I just get a "This page is not available" error from Chrome. That could be due to the same reason as why I'm blocked from my site, but idk.

Comment: It turns out that my multiple login attempts tripped their firewall and I was blocked. They have since removed the ban and I can each my site again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ADSL to access internet from the router, check the MTU settings, particularly if you ever had other sites with the same problem even if is just a few. Try setting the ADSL MTU to 1470 or so.

I’ve had this problem on several computers.

Comment: I use an Apple Airport base station for my WiFi so idk if I have these settings/where they are.

Comment: Also, why would it just randomly stop working, only for my site, after having worked for that site for over a month?

Comment: Alright, so I tried pinging with a packet size of 1470 (command `ping strongjoshua.com -f -l 1470` -f can be omitted), but although the ping request is sent, all requests time out.

Comment: @JakeGould Yeah, it wouldn't explain why this issue only happens with 1 site and only just recently. The traceroute also fails in Toronto Ontario, which I believe is where the EasyDNS hosting servers are, which makes it all the more strange that the connection error is only happening on my home network.